# The link you followed has expired.Please try again.in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes

i am trying to install a new theme in WordPress.I get a message that says "The link you followed has expired. Please try again."No matter what theme I try to install.

i add the following line to the code according to some solution on the internet
but still, I get the same error"The link you followed has expired. Please try again"

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

You can also check http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/

thanks

Answer (score 11):

i solve this error by change a PHP.ini file.
to do so go to wamp>PHP>php.ini file 
change the configuration to :

```
post_max_size = 750M 
upload_max_filesize = 750M 
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000  
memory_limit = 1000M
```

- save the changes.

click on wamp icon and restart all the services

Answer (score 3):

You just need to update the .htaccess and the wp-config.php files

**.htaccess**

```
php_value memory_limit 256
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 1000
```

above the:

```
# END WordPress
```

**wp-config.php**

```
@ini_set('upload_max_size' , '100M' );
@ini_set('memory_limit' , '256' );
@ini_set('upload_max_filesize' , '100M' );
@ini_set('post_max_size' , '100M' );
@ini_set('max_execution_time' , '300' );
@ini_set('max_input_time' , '1000' );
```

above the:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Answer (score 2):

You should update both .htaccess file and php.ini file:

**.htaccess**

```
php_value memory_limit 256
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 1000
```

**php.ini**

```
memory_limit = 256M
upload_max_size = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to set below configurations in `phpForApache.ini` file. Setting those in `php.ini` file did not work for me.

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```